# route is not loading component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor

My route is not loading my component. Not sure what is not working correctly. if I try to go some other component, It works fine but not for this component.

// routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { RecoverPassword } from '../../ui/pages/recover-password';

Meteor.startup(() => {
ReactDOM.render((
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       <Route exect path="/" component={ RecoverPassword }/>
    </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
 ),
 document.getElementById('react-root')
);
```

//recoverpassword.js

```
import React from 'react';
export default class RecoverPassword extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log('hi');
}
render() {
  return(
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: YOu have a typo exect instead of exact

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo error exect instead of exact

Change

```
  <Route exect path="/" component={ RecoverPassword }/>
```

To

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={ RecoverPassword }/>
```

ALso since you are exporting RecoverPassword component as default you need to import it like

```
  import RecoverPassword from '../../ui/pages/recover-password';
```

If you use only export without default then the component can be imported like

```
 import { RecoverPassword } from '../../ui/pages/recover-password';
```

Also if you are not using React v16 Then return jsx elements by enclosing with div or span

```
   import React from 'react';
   export default class RecoverPassword extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       console.log('hi');
    }
    render() {
       return(
       <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
       </div>
     );
  }
```

If you are using React v16 then enclose jsx elements in React.Fragment

```
   import React from 'react';
   export default class RecoverPassword extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       console.log('hi');
    }
    render() {
       return(
       <React.Fragment>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
       </React.Fragment>
     );
  }
```

Comment: @SharjeelShahid You are welcome. Kindly do upvote and accept the answer on your choice whichever helped you resolving the issue

Answer (score 1):

Beside the typo of `Route exact`,

You are exporting a default module:

```
export default class RecoverPassword ...
```

But importing it as it was a named export:

```
import { RecoverPassword } from '../../ui/pages/recover-password';
```

You should import it as default, so change it to this (no curly braces):

```
import RecoverPassword from '../../ui/pages/recover-password';
```

You can read more about exports and imports [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import)

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked for me :)